# Using Prisma and transactions?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I am trying to make prisma rollback my transaction. I use the following code:

```
await globals.prisma.$transaction(async () => {
    try {
        return await o.SaveDetails(taintedResponse);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("No, not good");
    }
});
```

And I do my save in SaveDetails method, but on the line after, I do this:

```
throw new Error("Dingity!");
```

In my mind, that would make Prisma calling the rollback-function of the transaction. But no. Everything is saved in the database.

I have also been trying to call raw SQL and when doing so, I can use:

```
await globals.prisma.$executeRawUnsafe("begin");
await globals.prisma.$executeRawUnsafe("... just random update");
//await globals.prisma.$executeRawUnsafe("rollback");
await globals.prisma.$executeRawUnsafe("commit");
```

And the update either commits or rolls back depending on the last two lines. However, when I use the same "begin" and "rollback" but with Prisma-statements in between, they always stick regardless if I call rollback afterwards.

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing?

Regards.